# how can we assign input type in to an variable

Tags: php, input

Here I am having an doubt,i know it doesn't look relevant to you people but i need to get it. The thing is can we assign an input type to an variable like this.

```
<?php  $option  = '<input type="text" name="project_id" id="pr_id"/>';
var_dump($option);?>
```

Here `pr_id` contains an value and a thinking to assign it to an variable

Comment: I'm not sure I know what you're asking. Can you explain it a little bit further or include some examples?

Comment: Php executes on the server side, so you need to use a POST request to send the value of the input to php.

Comment: what you've done there is declare a string which looks like some HTML markup. On its own this does nothing. Are you intending to echo that to the screen at some point? Are you asking how to capture what the user enters into the textbox after you've rendered it to the page? If so, then take an introductory tutorial on using HTML forms and PHP to post data back to the server. A good one will explain all the key concepts. Remember that your PHP needs to execute twice - once to send the HTML form to the client, and again later to receive the response containing the form data, and process it.

Comment: What do you want exactly? Currently you're setting the HTML element as a string to a variable. Do you want to hold a reference to the input so that you can read it's value? Do you want to replace `pr_id` by some variable?

Comment: @Stefan i know that but any other way of passing that `id="pr_id"` value in to an variable

Comment: @ADyson @Glubus  the thing is my `id="pr_id"` contains an value for example take it as 3 now   i want to pass that value in to an variable.

Comment: I think there is no other way of doing it, except a post request.

Comment: @user_777 do u want to assign as a variable or id to input box? If yes means, when? while loading or submitting a button?

Comment: 'id="pr_id"' is just a string, nothing else. It doesn't contain a value. You'll need to clarify what you want. Where is this value that you're talking about? Are you talking about getting the value which the user has entered into the text box? Or adding a value to it which comes from your server/database? I feel like you need to take a tutorial, you seem to be missing an understanding of some of the basics, otherwise I think you would be able to express your requirement more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can assign anything! Here's an Input object I just created, have a look at this:

```
<?php

class Input
{
    /** @var array $attributes */
    private $attributes = [];

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @return mixed|string
     */
    public function getAttribute($key)
    {
        return isset($this->attributes[$key]) ? $this->attributes[$key] : null;
    }

    /**
     * @param $key
     * @param $value
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAttribute($key, $value)
    {
        $this->attributes[$key] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param array $attributes
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setAttributes(array $attributes)
    {
        $this->attributes = $attributes;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAttributes()
    {
        return $this->attributes;
    }

    public function render()
    {
        $html =  '<input ';
        foreach ($this->getAttributes() as $key => $val) {
            $html .= $key.'="'.$val.'" ';
        }
        $html .= '/>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

So you can now generate an Input with the following code:

```
$input = new Input();
$input->setAttribute('id', 'pr_id')
      ->setAttribute('name', 'project_id')
      ->setAttribute('type', 'text');

echo $input->render();
```

Which outputs:

`<input id="pr_id" name="project_id" type="text" />`

Have a play with it here: https://3v4l.org/sAiWd